# IF statement will not work

Tags: php

I am trying to grab favorite posts from 'posts_fav' where the post id is of the row id. Then i want it to if the userid on the query equals the members id it will show 'yes' otherwise it will show 'No'.

Originial:

```
foreach ($usersfav as $rowfav) {
    if ($rowfav["user_id"] == $member["id"]) 
    {
        echo 'yes'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

One of my attempts:
This changes all to the else function. Skips the check of the if as there needs to be a way I can get $rowfav[""] without needing

```
foreach ($usersfav as $rowfav) {
    $sqlfav = "SELECT * FROM posts_fav WHERE post_id = '".$row["id"]."'";
    $stmfav = $dbh->prepare($sqlfav);
    $stmfav->execute(); 
    $usersfav = $stmfav->fetchAll();

    if ($rowfav["user_id"] == $member["id"]) 
    {
        echo 'yes'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

**Update:**
So I want the posts where rowfav["user_id"] and member["id"] match up to say 'Yes' and other posts without any rows that can be found to say 'no'

Full code:

```
$sql = "
SELECT *,
(SELECT profilepic FROM users WHERE users.username = users_profiles_comments.author) AS profilepic
FROM users_profiles_comments WHERE postid = '". $row["username"] ."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";


$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$users = $stm->fetchAll();



foreach ($users as $row) {
echo ' <div class="row user-row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"
                     src="'.$row['profilepic'].'" width="150px;"
                     alt="User Pic">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><b>'. $row["author"] .'</b> - <small>'. $row["date"] .'</small>
                ';
                if ($row["author"]) {
                echo '<p style="float:right;">';
$sqlfav = "SELECT * FROM posts_fav WHERE post_id = '".$row["id"]."'";
$stmfav = $dbh->prepare($sqlfav);
$stmfav->execute(); 
$usersfav = $stmfav->fetchAll();

foreach ($usersfav as $rowfav) {
if (strcmp($rowfav["user_id"], $member["id"]) == 0)
        {
            echo '
                Yes
                '; 
        }
        else { 
echo 'No';
            } }
```

Comment: @PopoFibo 500 service error. Wont work.

Comment: @PopoFibo Wait sorry `if (strcmp($rowfav["user_id"], $member["id"]))` is this what I change it to? This seemed to get away from the error. Anyways, the post which is meant to be... a yes now says no. And all the other posts without no row in the table say nothing.

Comment: @PopoFibo Updated the bottom of my question, with what I would like to do.

Comment: no, for equating you check the value (if equal it should be 0), `if (strcmp($rowfav["user_id"], $member["id"]) == 0)`

Comment: @PopoFibo Stays the same. says YES on the first post with info from table, and nothing on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (count($usersfav)!=0)
{
    foreach ($usersfav as $rowfav) 
    {
        if (strcmp($rowfav["user_id"], $member["id"]) == 0)
        {
          echo 'Yes'; 
        }
    }
}
else 
{ 
    echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: It only appears on one post. The else function is meant to show what it says on the posts without anything in the table.

Comment: Updated the bottom of my question, with what I would like to do.

Comment: Updated answer. If "SELECT" returned empty result, your $rowfaw is not  set

Comment: This now shows 'no' on every post. Even the first post which if ($rowfav["user_id"] == $member["id"]) is true on.

Comment: Can you show full code, with SQL and $usersfav generation part?

Comment: Changed my answer again. Maybe need use **if (isset($usersfav))**

Comment: It write 'NO' to all posts or 'NO' for wrong and nothing for correct?

Comment: Solved it! Just added: `if ($usersfav == false) {
    echo '
    no
    '; 
      }` The ones with a row say yes, and the ones without say no. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you want to get the favourite posts of a user, and with that, get the information that it's his post or not.

You could, as a suggestion, let the check be done on the query, so your results would come already with the flag you want.

```
$sql = "SELECT posts_fav.*, posts.*, IF(posts.user_id = ?, 1, 0) as owns_post FROM posts_fav LEFT JOIN posts ON posts_fav.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts_fav.member_id = ?";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("posts_member_id", $member["id"]);
$query->bind_param("member_id", $member["id"]);
$query->execute(); 
$rows = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row["owns_post"]) {
       echo "User owns the post";
    } else {
       echo "User does not own the post";
    }
}
```

Not tested, no garantee that it even works. :-)

Comment: Also, no. I want it to be on all posts no matter if the post is his/hers. If the post id and the members id is in the table of posts_fav [user_id, post_id] I want it to show 'yes' and if it does not exist I want it to show 'no'.

Comment: Hmm so you will be doing a query for each post to see if the user favorited it?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: just a question, did you change my query in the end to posts_fav.user_id? I don't know what is the name of the column where you keep the user_id, but I suppose it's that one.

Comment: I just saw your full source. A few points: I see you use $row variable in the first statement, where does it come from? That same variable also will be overwritten in the next foreach statement. And where did the $member come from? These informations could be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: $member comes from a config.php file, which reads a cookie/session to tell if user is logged in. And $row in the first statement comes from above where it tells what profile it is on.

Comment: and postid = '". $row["username"] ."' do you really want to compare postid with username?

Comment: Ah yes I do. I've actually stored the username into postid. But this really has nothing to do with the favourite posts..

Comment: Could you throw in some var_dumps there, namely var_dump($member) and var_dump($usersfav) after the posts_fav query, and give us the result?

Comment: $member =  `array(23) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(5) "Admin"`

Comment: $usersfav = `array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["post_id"]=> string(2) "62" [2]=> string(2) "62" } }`

Comment: Solved it! Just added: `if ($usersfav == false) {
    echo '
    no
    '; 
      }` The ones with a row say yes, and the ones without say no. I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: The previous user answer should be correct, with perhaps changing if (count($usersfav)!=0) to if(!empty($usersfav)) or if(is_array($usersfav)), and accepted. Good luck with your project.